# non-conformable arrays when execute accuracy in R to c#

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I run this code in R, it's can display the output. But when I connected this code from C# (I used `RDotNet` as connector) this code can't execute. The error message shows:

> "Error in `-.default`(dx, fits) : non-conformable arrays"

Why this error occurs?

```
tt<-ts(runif(10,min=1,max=10),frequency=1)
h<-HoltWinters(tt,beta=FALSE,gamma=FALSE)
accuracy(h)
                    ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE     MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.7050429 2.143595 1.872015 37.17607 63.57751 0.731255 -0.3005824
```

Here's the C# code:

```
NumericVector u = engine.CreateNumericVector(t); 
engine.SetSymbol("matdt", u); 
NumericMatrix matdata = engine.Evaluate("matdt").AsNumericMatrix(); 
engine.Evaluate("library('forecast')"); 
engine.Evaluate("g<-HoltWinters(ts(matdt,frequency=1),beta=FALSE,gamma=FALSE)"); 
engine.Evaluate("accuracy(g)[,5]");
```

Comment: It would be nice to see how you use R.NET, the problem may be there.

Comment: <code> NumericVector u = engine.CreateNumericVector(t);
            engine.SetSymbol("matdt", u);
            NumericMatrix matdata = engine.Evaluate("matdt").AsNumericMatrix();
            engine.Evaluate("library('forecast')");
            engine.Evaluate("g<-HoltWinters(ts(matdt,frequency=1),beta=FALSE,gamma=FALSE)");
            engine.Evaluate("accuracy(g)[,5]"); @tonytonov

Comment: Please provide more information about your environment. The code sample even in R does not work, using package forecast v 6.1, R 3.2.1 x64 on windows. I get an "Error in accuracy(h) : 
  First argument should be a forecast object or a time series."